# Objeto PRIMAVERA para as alterações mensais

Tags: vba

Bom dia,

Necessito de saber se existe algum  objeto PRIMAVERA no vba para o ecrã das alterações mensais pois necessito de fazer validações quando é lançada uma falta.

Comment: Não não existe.

Comment: Necessitava de quando for lançada uma falta injustificada esta descontasse vencimento da semana se essa falta fosse anterior ou posterior a um feriado/dia de descanso, com o ERP apenas é permitido fazer esta operação para descontar subsidio de alimentação, qual a forma que me aconselhava de realizar esta operação?

Answer (score 4):

Bom dia Hugo.

Julgo que a melhor opção que possas ter é executar algum VBA quando abres a empresa uma vez que não tens nenhum objeto no VBA que esteja relacionado com RH.
Nesse VBA, poderias fazer uma query para te devolver todas as faltas injustificadas nos últimos "X" dias que inda não tivessem sido processadas.

> select * from CadastroFaltas where NumProc = 0 and Falta = 'FXPTO'

Para cada registo devolvido, desmarcaria a falta se esta obedece-se às condições referidas ("*se essa falta fosse anterior ou posterior a um feriado/dia de descanso*") e marcaria uma nova falta injustificada (outro código) para o período determinado ("*semana*").

Inserir alteração mensal: `Aplicacao.BSO.RecursosHumanos.AltMensaisDescontos.Actualiza`

Eliminar alteração mensal: `Aplicacao.BSO.RecursosHumanos.AltMensaisDescontos.Remove`

Para definires o período (semana) onde marcar as novas faltas injustificadas, deverás obter qual a semana do ano em que a falta a eliminar se encontra (`Format(Date, "ww")`) e depois obter o primeiro e ultimo dia dessa semana para marcar as "novas" faltas.